# WSL 2 cannot reach intranet host under VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm unable to reach intranet IPs from the WSL when I'm under VPN. If I try to ping these IPs from CMD it works, but it does not work when I'm trying the same thing from a wsl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the WSL network interface in Windows Firewall with the following command:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow
```

I had to reboot Windows, since I don't have full control, in order for the rule to take effect.